# Coerce and order character vector to factor, with factor levels ordered by another vector

Tags: r

Imagine a data set like this:

```
# creating data for test
set.seed(1839)
id <- as.character(1:10)
frequency <- sample(c("n", "r", "s", "o", "a"), 10, TRUE)
frequency_value <- sapply(
  frequency, switch, "n" = -2, "r" = -1, "s" = 0, "o" = 1, "a" = 2
)
(test <- data.frame(id, frequency, frequency_value))
```

Which looks like:

```
   id frequency frequency_value
1   1         a               2
2   2         o               1
3   3         r              -1
4   4         o               1
5   5         o               1
6   6         s               0
7   7         n              -2
8   8         n              -2
9   9         r              -1
10 10         n              -2
```

The variable `frequency` has the response I'm interested in. It goes from never to rarely to sometimes to often to always. The labels are just the first letter of each of those words. The order is presented in `frequency_value`.

What I would like to do is make `frequency` a factor with levels in the order n, r, s, o, a. However, I want to make this dependent on the values in `frequency_value`. They should follow the order that is preserved in `frequency_value` and *not* be simply hard-coded (like one would do with `factor(frequency, levels = c("n", "r", "s", "o", "a"))`).

I have thought about using this, a `tidyverse` solution:

```
levels <- test[, c("frequency", "frequency_value")] %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  arrange(as.numeric(frequency_value)) %>% 
  pull(frequency) %>% 
  as.character()
test$frequency <- factor(test$frequency, levels)
```

But that seems to be computationally inefficient when I do this on big data sets with more than one variable that I want to make factor. Is there a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once option could be by just using `dplyr` as:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- test %>% arrange(frequency_value) %>% 
  mutate(frequency = factor(frequency, levels = unique(frequency))) 

test

#    id frequency frequency_value
# 1   7         n              -2
# 2   8         n              -2
# 3  10         n              -2
# 4   3         r              -1
# 5   9         r              -1
# 6   6         s               0
# 7   2         o               1
# 8   4         o               1
# 9   5         o               1
# 10  1         a               2

str(test)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ id             : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","10","2","3",..: 8 9 2 4 10 7 3 5 6 1
# $ frequency      : Factor w/ 5 levels "n","r","s","o",..: 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 5
# $ frequency_value: num  -2 -2 -2 -1 -1 0 1 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use order for `unique` combinations (what you were using) within `with`:

```
test$frequency <- factor(test$frequency, 
                         with(unique(test[, -1]), frequency[order(frequency_value)]))
```

> ```
> [1] a o r o o s n n r n
> Levels: 
> n r s o a
> ```